# Different classes with same serialversion uid

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I am having a strange doubt. All I want to know is,

suppose if I have two classes, (**100% same structure**) in two different locations (packages or projects), and I take care of generating the **same serialVersionUID for both**, can I safely say it's right to serialize using one class and de-serialize using another?

P.S. I understand that it's not good to keep the same class in two separate places, but that's not the question right now.

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ObjectInputStream will read the original fully qualified class name of the object from input data and will try to create an instance of this class. You cannot change that. Serialization will be looking for the original class no matter what serialVersionUID is.

Comment: Thanks. With this I understand I need to use the same class ONLY. I hope its right.

Comment: Absolutely. Actually you can use the class only in one way - to cast the object you read with readObject

Comment: So what happens when you deserialize the class (without casting, keeping the Object returned by readObject) when you don't have the "original" class in your classpath? Will it still throw a ClassCastException or can you use reflection to access its members and values?

Comment: If we don't have the original class on classpath readObject will throw ClassNotFoundException