# Share class between programs

Tags: java

I have created a small application that connects to a server that can handle more than one connections. In my java project I have the following classes:

- `Client.java` Client who connects to the server (Application 1)
- `Server.java` Waits for connections and start a ServerThread (see below) (Application 2)
- `ServerThread.java` Each connection has its own thread that runs in this class
- `CustomObject.java` An object that contains a few different variables that I send back and forth from the server.

I send it like this:

```
out.writeObject(new CustomObject()); // out = objectOutputStream
```

And then I receive at the server application like this:

```
co = (CustomObject) in.readObject(); // in = objectInputStream
```

And this works great when I run it within my project (first start the server application and then two instances of the client application). However if the Server and ServerThread classes aren't in the same eclipse project as the Client and CustomObject classes it gives me an error for the last line of code I posted where I cast `in.readObject();`. "ClassNotFoundException" (even though the server project has an exact copy of CustomObject).

How can I fix this? I want to be able to export and run the server as one program and then the client as one when I export them from eclipse. Let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to put the server and client in the same Eclipse project:

1. Both Server and Client can have a main() and be in the same project.
2. Create two separate run configurations in eclipse (one for Server, one for Client) -- note that run configurations are created automatically if they don't exist when you press the "play" button in eclipse (just make sure the file that has the main() method is open in the editor when you press play), so you probably won't need to do this manually.
3. Then, in eclipse, when you export the program, export it as a Runnable JAR (if "Runnable JAR" isn't available in the export quick menu just select "Other..." and search for it). You can select the run configuration. So export one for client (maybe name it client.jar) and one for the server (maybe name it server.jar).

You can have many applications in one project, as long as you select the appropriate run configuration when you export a Runnable JAR.

Another solution, which is more common for larger projects when perhaps every application shouldn't be in the same project file (e.g. you don't want to distribute the code for one application with another, or maybe some are not built with Eclipse, etc.), is to put the common stuff in its *own* project. Then, you can either a) add that project to the build configuration for the other projects you are using it in, or b) export it as a JAR and use that JAR in your other projects.

Comment: I think an easier solution would be to create 3 separate projects (Server, "Core", Client) and then export the core project (which will contain the `CustomObject` class and other necessary classes that are shared between the server and client) as a jar file, and then import that jar file as a dependency on both the server and client.

Comment: I'm not sure how that qualifies as easier. :) But it's definitely the right way, especially for larger projects -- which is why I suggested it as the alternative option. The OPs project seems small enough (based on his description) that a single project and a pair of run configurations would be adequate. Another case for many applications in one project is test applications for a library. You are right, though; a separate project for shared code is a better general solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the class definition available on the JVM where client is running for the readObject() to be able to successfully de-serialize it. So you should have two jar files as below

**Server Jar**

- Server.class
- ServerThread.class
- CustomObject.class

**Client Jar**

- Client.class
- CustomObject.class

You can use RMI as a higher level abstraction if you are writing a big application.

Comment: If you're working entirely in Eclipse, it doesn't provide the flexibility to selectively include class files in an exported JAR. When you export a JAR, you get all the files in that project's tree. This solution would work with a more flexible build tool, but with Eclipse it would be a bit of a kludge.

Comment: @boxed__l: Yes. `readObject()` returns an object of whatever type was serialized. *What* you try and cast it to has no effect on the actual object that `readObject()` reads and returns. If the cast is not valid, you get a `ClassCastException`, but `readObject()` itself is unaffected by that. It's precisely the same as if you did: `Object obj = new CustomObject(); ABC abc = (ABC)obj;`.

Comment: I would be interested to know if Java actually dynamically defines a class according to the result of deserialization. :-) Then casting operation would be checking the match between that class "self-definition" and an already-known class...

Comment: [Answers both our doubts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683630/different-classes-with-same-serialversion-uid) :P @Matthieu